# Java run loop with CompletableFuture

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, completable-future

I am trying to use CompletableFuture to execute `for` loop in parallel. And inside the loop I use `supplyAsync` to call `doSomething` to get output string and then put it in HashMap:

```
    ...
    ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    CompletableFuture<?> completableFuture = null;

    for ( int i = 0; i < numberOfRecords; i++ ) {
        final int finalI = i;
        completableFuture = CompletableFuture
                .supplyAsync( () -> doSomething( data, finalI ) )
                .thenAccept( str -> map.put( finalI, str ) );
    }
    completableFuture.join();

private String doSomething(HashMap<String, String> data, int finalI ) ) {
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

    for ( int k = 0; k < data.size(); k++ ) {
    //process data and add it in queue
    }
    String result = processQueueAndReturnString(queue);
    return result;
```

The problem is when `for` loop is almost done ( when `i` is close to `numberOfRecords`), another `for` loop inside `doSomething` method skips some iterations, e.g. if `k=5` it can run loop only until `k=2 or 3` and in this case `supplyAsync( () -> doSomething( data, finalI ) )` returns `null`. So it seems like my `for` loop with `CompletableFuture` finishes until some iterations are completely done.

Any suggestions or hints on how to fix that?

Comment: You do not show us the `HashMap<String, String>` you call `data`. Is that map not thread-safe? Is there code not shown that alters that map? If would be more useful if you could post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @BasilBourque `HashMap data` is not thread-safe, should it be? I just use it in method `doSomething` to get entry value based on index `finalI ` I don't process that HashMap - I just read it.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to do or what everything means, but note you are only waiting for the last future to complete. If you want to wait for all to complete then collect the futures and join on `CompletableFuture#allOf(...)`.

Comment: You seem to be passing to all your tasks a reference to a single `HashMap<String, String>`. That map is not thread-safe, yet all your tasks across all your threads are accessing that map, in a for-loop. And you complain of that for-loop malfunctioning. Putting 2 and 2 together, I'm guessing you have a thread-safety problem using a non-thread-safe map across threads. But you have provided far too little information, so I can only guess. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @BasilBourque - Based on the OP's comments, my diagnosis is that the map is OK.  The real problem is something else.  Only the last future was joined, so the code after the loop was not waiting properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So it seems like my `for` loop with `CompletableFuture` finishes [before] some iterations are completely done.

Each loop iteration in your example code creates a `CompletableFuture`.  If you want to wait for all of the work to complete, you need to join **all** of them, not just the one created by the last iteration.

Something like this (style corrected!):

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
CompletableFuture<Void>[] futures = new CompletableFuture<Void>[nosRecords];

for (int i = 0; i < nosRecords; i++) {
    final int finalI = i;
    futures[i] = CompletableFuture
            .supplyAsync(() -> doSomething(data, finalI))
            .thenAccept(str -> map.put(finalI, str));
}
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures);
```

Note that you need to change `CompletableFuture<?>` to `CompletableFuture<Void>` because the declaration of `allOf()` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf(java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...))) requires that.  Fortunately, the `thenAccept(...)` call is already returning a `CompletableFuture<Void>`.

---

> The `HashMap` `data` is not thread-safe, should it be? I just use it in method `doSomething` to get entry value based on index `finalI`.  I don't process that `HashMap`. I just read it.

There will be a *happens before* between the `supplyAsync` call and the call to its lambda argument.  So provided that `data` does not change during the execution of any of the `doSomething` calls, they will all see the correct values in the `data` map.

Assuming things are as you said (and remain that way), it is OK to use an non-synchronized `HashMap` there.

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65527042/642706) looks correct, and is appropriate for today's Java. But in the future (ahhh, see what I did there?), Java may offer a simpler and much faster approach, with virtual threads.

## Project Loom

[Project Loom](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/loom/) is coming to Java, with preliminary [builds available now](http://jdk.java.net/loom/) built on early-access Java 16.

One major feature is virtual threads ([fibers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(computer_science))). These are lightweight threads. When the flow-of-control in any virtual thread blocks, Java detects the block and switches in another virtual thread to keep the CPU core busy. This can massively speed up threaded code that frequently blocks (as opposed to strictly CPU-bound tasks like video-encoding).

Note that according to Ron Pressler, one of the people working on Project Loom, the need for most of the many methods on `CompletableFuture` evaporates with virtual threads. You will likely not do more than call `get`. See his presentations, the latest being [2020-11-11](https://youtu.be/zuc9JZz9Xbw?t=580), [2020-09-17](https://youtu.be/fOEPEXTpbJA), and [2020-07-28](https://youtu.be/23HjZBOIshY).

While I did not capture all the nuances of your business logic, I think I got the gist of it. Similar to Stephen C, I collect all the returned `CompletableFuture` objects. Then I inspect them to see if they completed successfully or not.

In Project Loom, the [`ExecutorService`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/loom/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) is now [`AutoCloseable`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/loom/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html). So we can use try-with-resources syntax. The end of your try-block will block until all the submitted tasks are done. This natural blocking replaces the `CompletableFuture.allOf(futures);` seen in the solution by Stephen C.

### Sample code

Here is a class for our task, a `Callable` that returns a `UUID` object. We also sleep each task for a second, to demonstrate a lengthy task. Our task also records its results in a `ConcurrentMap` we pass to its constructor.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class DoSomething implements Callable < UUID >
{
    private Integer identifier;
    private ConcurrentMap < Integer, UUID > results;

    // Constructor
    public DoSomething ( Integer identifier , ConcurrentMap < Integer, UUID > resultsMap )
    {
        this.identifier = identifier;
        this.results = resultsMap;
    }

    @Override
    public UUID call ( ) throws Exception
    {
        Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 1 ) );
        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        this.results.put( this.identifier , uuid );
        return uuid;
    }
}
```

Here is the code to instantiate and run a bunch of those tasks.

```java
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "INFO - Java version: " + Runtime.version() );
        System.out.println( "INFO - Host OS: " + System.getProperty( "os.name" ) + " version " + System.getProperty( "os.version" ) );
        System.out.println( "INFO - arch: " + System.getProperty( "os.arch" ) + " | Available processors (cores): " + Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() );
        long maxMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
        System.out.println( "INFO - Maximum memory (bytes): " + String.format( Locale.getDefault() , "%,d" , ( maxMemory == Long.MAX_VALUE ? "no limit" : maxMemory ) ) );
        System.out.println( "----------------------------------------------" );
        long start = System.nanoTime();

        ConcurrentMap < Integer, UUID > results = new ConcurrentSkipListMap <>();
        int countTasks = 1_000_000;
        System.out.println( "INFO - Starting a run of " + countTasks + ". " + Instant.now() );
        List < CompletableFuture < UUID > > futures = new ArrayList <>( countTasks );
        try (
                ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadExecutor() ;
        )
        {
            for ( int nthTask = 0 ; nthTask < countTasks ; nthTask++ )
            {
                executorService.submit( new DoSomething( nthTask , results ) );
            }
        }
        // At this point, flow-of-control blocks until all submitted tasks finish (are done, or are cancelled).
        List < CompletableFuture < UUID > > canceled = new ArrayList <>();
        List < CompletableFuture < UUID > > completedExceptionally = new ArrayList <>();
        for ( CompletableFuture < UUID > future : futures )
        {
            if ( future.isCancelled() )
            {
                canceled.add( future );
            } else if ( future.isCompletedExceptionally() )
            {
                completedExceptionally.add( future );
            } else if ( ! future.isDone() )
            {
                throw new IllegalStateException( "All tasks should be done at this point, normally or interrupted." );
            } else
            {
                throw new IllegalStateException( "Should not be able to reach this point." );
            }
        }

        Duration duration = Duration.ofNanos( System.nanoTime() - start );
        System.out.println( "Done at " + Instant.now() + ". Took: " + duration );
        System.out.println( "Problems… canceled size: " + canceled.size() + " | completedExceptionally size: " + completedExceptionally.size() );
        System.out.println( "Results size = " + String.format( Locale.getDefault() , "%,d" , results.size() ) );
    }
```

```
INFO - Java version: 16-loom+9-316
INFO - Host OS: Mac OS X version 10.14.6 
INFO - arch: x86_64 | Available processors (cores): 6
INFO - Maximum memory (bytes): 8,589,934,592
----------------------------------------------
INFO - Starting a run of 10000000. 2021-01-01T05:40:28.564019Z
Done at 2021-01-01T05:41:11.567852Z. Took: PT43.006895236S
Problems… canceled size: 0 | completedExceptionally size: 0
Results size = 10,000,000
```

Running a million of those tasks takes several seconds. Running ten million takes less than a minute.

So you can see how the blocked threads sleeping for a second are obviously not taking up time on a core. If they were taking time on the cores, we'd be waiting a long while: 10,000,000 tasks * 1 second each / 6 cores = 1,666,666 seconds = 462 hours.